# Sign In Live Account with scope wl.signin request too many permissions

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, onedrive

In my Windows Phone app I use SignInButton with a single scope wl.signin to connect Microsoft Live account. After I put my email and password, the API shows me a page with the following permissions it needs:

1. Access name, gender, picture, etc...
2. Access and **edit** your OneDrive
3. **Access your photos and videos**
4. **Access your info anytime**

I just want to have only permission to read files from OneDrive and not edit them so p. 3, 4 and 2 (partially) are not required for me.

**What scopes do I need to use to connect the OneDrive account with Read Only permission for files?**

Thanks

UPDATED:
Button in xaml:

```
<live:SignInButton
          Scopes="wl.signin, wl.basic" 
          Branding="Skydrive" ClientId="xxxxxxxxxxx" 
          TextType="Connect" SessionChanged="SignInSkyDriveSessionChanged">
</live:SignInButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

`wl.basic` and `wl.skydrive` as [desribed here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn631845.aspx).

`wl.basic` - Read access to a user's basic profile info. Also enables read access to a user's list of contacts.
`wl.skydrive` - Read access to a user's files stored in OneDrive.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: if page will be changed, behavior will be changed too. Because the link to the official documentation about skydrive.

Comment: Either way, you should include the gist of your "answer" here. Providing a link to something you found isn't really an answer, it's a comment.

Comment: No, it didn't change anything and still requires extra-permissions. Maybe I should change something in my App in my Live Account settings? But I've just looked at those settings and didn't find anything which was related to permissions.

Comment: try to remove `wl.signin`

Comment: No I can't, because I will not be signed in at all

Comment: I tried to use only basic permission - no success and still asks me for edit permission